# python sh module is not accepting variable as command

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I am reading a list of unix command line programs from a file into a list, pList.
All of the programs are in my PATH.
I then assign one of the entries to a variable: prog.

I would then like to execute that program using the non standard module sh

```
sh.prog('arguments')
```

However, sh interprets the name prog literally, and not as a variable containing a string.  It looks for the program prog, which doesn't exist. Is there a way around this problem? Would using the subprocess call function have the same problem?
How can I get around this?

Comment: Yes! It works exactly as you put it. Make it an official answer, and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Found a better solution (see below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sh` module has a [`Command`](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/command_class.html#command-class) class for situations like this.

```
sh.Command(prog)('arguments')
```

Comment: Thanks!

I saw that in the documentation, but I misunderstood it.